# python 3.5.1 syntax error on an if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a homework assignment, it looks like this:

```
def main():
    keep_going = 'y'
    number_of_salespeople = 0

    while keep_going == 'y' or keep_going == 'Y':
        process_sales()
        number_of_salespeople += 1
        keep_going = input('Are there more salespeople? (enter y or Y for yes) ')

    print(' ')
    print('There were', number_of_salespeople, 'salespeople today.')

def process_sales():        
    print(' ')
    name = input('What is the salesperson\'s name? ')

    first_sale_amount = float(input('What is', name, '\'s first sale amount? '))
    while 0 <= first_sale_amount <= 25000:
        print('Error: that is not a valid sales amount. The amount must be greater than 0')
        first_sale_amount = float(input('Please enter a correct sale amount: '))

    highest_sale = first_sale_amount
    lowest_sale = first_sale_amount
    average_sale = first_sale_amount

    number_of_sales = float(input('How many sales did', name, 'make this month? '))

    for number in range(2, number_of_sales + 1):
        sale_amount = float(input('Enter', name, '\'s time for sale #' + str(number) + ': '))
        while 0 <= sale_amount <= 25000:
            print('Error: that is not a valid sales amount. The amount must be greater than 0')
            sale_amount = float(input('Please enter a correct sale amount: '))

    if sale_amount > highest_sale:
        highest_sale = sale_amount

    else sale_amount < lowest_sale:
        lowest_sale = sale_amount

    total_sales += sale_amount
    average_sale = (first_sale_amount + total_sales) / number_of_sales

    print('The highest sale for', name, 'was', \
          format(highest_sale, ',.2f'), \
          sep='')

    print('The lowest sale for', name, 'was', \
          format(lowest_sale, ',.2f'), \
          sep='')

    print('The average sale for', name, 'was', \
          format(average_sale, ',.2f'), \
          sep='')

main()
```

the error I am having is in the if else statement towards the bottom,

```
if sale_amount > highest_sale:
    highest_sale = sale_amount

else sale_amount < lowest_sale:
    lowest_sale = sale_amount
```

the error looks like this:

> Syntax Error:         else sale_amount < lowest_sale:: , line
>   58, pos 24

I cannot see what the issue is, can anyone help me figure out where the error is coming from. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should study the basic syntax of python first. Take a look at the [`if` and `elif`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html) in python.

> There can be zero or more `elif` parts, and the `else` part is optional.
>   **The keyword `elif` is short for `else if`**, and is useful to avoid
>   excessive indentation.

So after the first `if` to check for more conditions, you need something like this:

```
if cond1:
   # do something
elif cond2:
   # do something else
# more elif branches if needed, and finally else if there is something default
else:
   # do the default thing
```

---

There are more issues with your code.

**1.** The `input` is wrong as more than one argument is passed. You can use string's [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method like this:

```
first_sale_amount = float(input("What is {}'s first sale amount?".format(name)))
```

**2.** The condition in `while` has wrong logic. If you want check if the entered value is **not** in the range of 0-25000 inclusive, you should put a `not` before the condition like so:

```
while not 0 <= first_sale_amount <= 25000:
        print('Error: that is not a valid sales amount. The amount must be greater than 0')
        first_sale_amount = float(input('Please enter a correct sale amount: '))
```

**and possibly 3, 4, 5 and so on.**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I figured there would be more errors in the code, the error I asked about was just the first that came up in the debugger and I couldn't for the life of me figure out why it wasn't working. I just finished up the whole assignment and have everything debugged and working correctly though. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`else` can't have a condition. Change to `elif` ("else if").